Can you order the execution of all expanded jobs in single rule?
I have a snakemake pipeline that runs a genetic analysis.  The genome has been split into many 'regions'.  These regions can run in parallel, and therefore I've used expand(), and they all run as expected.
regions = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4']
some_pattern = {region}/file.tsv
rule all:
    input: expand(some_pattern, region=regions)

and there is a subsequent rule
rule process_region:
    output: some_pattern
    run:
        ...

The issue is, some regions are much more computationally complex, and therefore take more time to run, therefore I would prefer if they were front-loaded so they don't hold up the pipeline for a long time at the end.  Is there a way I can order the execution of the expanded pattern?

After searching, the short answer is no, there is no way order jobs in the same rule, however there is a workaround that will have the desired effect.
Create 2 patterns and 2 rules, then use the priority flag to run the rule you need to first.
slow_regions = ['r1', 'r2']
regular_regions = ['r3', 'r4']

slow_pattern = {slow_region}/slow_file.tsv
regular_pattern = {regular_region}/file.tsv
rule all:
    input: expand(some_pattern, slow_region=slow_regions),
           expand(regular_pattern, regular_region=regular_regions)

and there the subsequent rules.  Note priority, also you might want to give it more resources as well.  The default priority is 0, so anything greater will run first.
rule process_slow_region:
    output: slow_pattern
    priority: 1
    threads: xx
    run:
        ...

rule process_regular_region:
    output: regular_pattern
    run:
        ...


EDIT : My previous answer was wrong, but apparently you can now set priorities to files directly at execution with the parameter --prioritize https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#priorities
I would say you can simply use:
snakemake [...] --prioritize r1/file.tsv r2/file.tsv
This can be set once and for all in a default workflow profile in your pipeline like this:
# in workflow/profiles/default/config.yaml
prioritize:
  - r1/file.tsv
  - r2/file.tsv


Does this actually work? I thought you would have to set the priorities directly on the process_region rule rather than on these new proxy rules, but maybe not.

You are right, it did not worked at all because the created target rules were never executed (the rule all had all the information needed). I fixed my answer with something that actually works.
